# Calculate Texture coordinates for procedural generated geometry

Tags: c++, opengl, game-engine

How can I calculate texture coordinates of such geometry?

The angle shown in the image (89.90 degree) may vary, therefore the geometry figure is changing and is not always such uniform.(maybe like geometry in the bottom of image) and red dots are generated procedurally depends on degree of smoothness given.

[image]

Comment: If you always generate 13 points this might sound like a point matching problem, (it's an optimization problem) where you look for the transform than maps one point set to another. Maybe you could have a look at what algorithms OpenCV has for this kind of problems (at least to get references)

Comment: Questions about mathematics should be on the math stack exchange.

Comment: It is not a math question, idiot.

Comment: It is purely a geometry question. That you ask it because you want to implement it in software doesn't mean much. The answer will be independent of any implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it by basic trigonometry.

For simplicity and convenience lets assume:

- coordinates **[0,0]** are in the middle of the geometry (where all the lines there intersect) and in the middle of the texture (and they map to each other - **[0,0]** in geometry is **[0,0]** in the texture).
- the texture coordinates span from **-1** to **1** (and also assume the geometry coordinates do too in the case of **90** degrees - in other cases it may get wider and shorter)
- possitive values for **x** span right and **y** up. And assume that **x** geometry axis is aligned with the **u** texture axis no matter the **angle** (which is 89.90 in your figures).

Something like this:
[image]

Then to transform from texture **[u,v]** to geometry **[x,y]** coordinates:

```
x = u + v*cos(angle)
y = v*sin(angle)
```

To illustrate, it is basically a shear transformation and scale transformation to preserve length of **y** (or alternatively - similar to rotation transform, but rotating only one axis - **y** - not both). If I reverse that transformation (to get the texture coordinates we want):

```
u = x - y*cotg(angle)
v = y/sin(angle)
```

With those equations I should be able to transform any geometry coordinates (a point) in the described situation into texture coordinates. For any **angle** in a **(0, 180)** range anyway

(Hopefully I didn't make too many embarrassing errors in there)

Comment: Execuse me but I cant understood what did you mean in the answer

Comment: Execuse me but I can't understood what did you not understand specifically. I simply provided the texture coordinates equation for the situation (as I understood it anyway).

Comment: Please can you illustrate your answer in a picture?

Answer (score 0):

I would take the easy way out and use either solid texturing or tri-planar [http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/use-tri-planar-texture-mapping-for-better-terrain--gamedev-13821] mapping.

If you really need uv, one option is to start with primitives that have a mapping and carry that over for every operation.

Creating uv after the fact will not get good results.